# How to change the format of a given date in DateTime variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I couldn't find the appropriate solution to my requirement.

I am passing the date through QueryString and reading it at destination as:

`string fromDateQS = Request.QueryString["FromDate"];`

I am getting the output in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. Whereas, I require the date to be in the format `mm-dd-yyyy`. How can I change the format?

Comment: You need to parse it as a DateTime.

Comment: But I am passing it as a string to the QueryString from the firstPage.

Comment: You still need to parse it as a DateTime

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: Did you mean `DateTime fromDateQS = DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["FromDate"]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String date = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["FromDate"], "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Comment: Getting the following exception at: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`: 

`An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: So, what should I do if the user picks a single digit date/month from the calendar? I don't know what the user will pick. The code has to work for all possible dates. Calendar gives out date as 7/12/2017 and not 07/12/2017.

Comment: So use `String date = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString["FromDate"], "MM/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");`. This will work for your case.

Comment: This will work for a date with single digit day: Such as `12/7/2017`. It won't work for `12/10/2017` as there is a two digit day `10`.

Comment: Check the length of the string. If length is 9, use "d", else use "dd".

Comment: I guessed that. But what if the month is `1-9` or Jan to Sept?

Comment: Dude, stick to a format and restrict the software/user choice. It will become a nightmare otherwise. Otherwise you have to rely on things like `TryParse` and hope that it will be interpreted in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

This exaple shows you 2 ways to transform your Dateinputstring into an output that adheres to your needs. You can use either of the static functions and provide them with `Request.QueryString["FromDate"]` as input - if that is a string.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    // **Solution 1:** 
    // Take your string, parse it into DateTime, print is as you like:
    public static string DateParser(string d)
    {
        string[] possibleFormats = new[]{"MM/dd/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy",
                                         "M/dd/yyyy", "M/d/yyyy"};

        DateTime parsedDate;

        // try each possible format
        foreach (var format in possibleFormats)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(d, format, 
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
            {
                return parsedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            }
        }
        // this will happen if the input is malformed
        return null;
    }

    // **Solution 2:**  
    // for your special case this will simply replace the `/` by `-`  
    // all the numbers are already in the correct locations...      
    public static string DateStringFixer(string d) {return d.Replace('/','-'); }
```

The following code is just for testing the outputs so you can verify it works. Use it in a Console Project - it generates about 370 / 11 pieces of DateTimes, formats them 4 ways and outputs them with both funcions.

It also outputs a piece of garbage DateTime-String at the end.

```
    public static void Test()
    {
      var dt = new DateTime (2017, 1, 1);

      // create testdates throughout the year, 11 days apart
      var dates = Enumerable.Range (0, 370).Where (r => r % 11 == 0)
                  .ToList ().Select (delta => dt.AddDays (delta));

      string dStr;
      string dStrAligned;
      foreach(var d in dates)
      {
          dStr = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
          dStrAligned = (dStr+"   ").Substring(0,10);
          Console.WriteLine(dStrAligned + "\tby Parsing: '" +  DateParser(dStr) + 
              "'\tby replace: '" + DateStringFixer(dStr));

          dStr = d.ToString("MM/d/yyyy");
          dStrAligned = (dStr+"   ").Substring(0,10);
          Console.WriteLine(dStrAligned + "\tby Parsing: '" + DateParser(dStr) +
              "'\tby replace: '" + DateStringFixer(dStr));

          dStr = d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy");
          dStrAligned = (dStr+"   ").Substring(0,10);
          Console.WriteLine(dStrAligned + "\tby Parsing: '" + DateParser(dStr) + 
              "'\tby replace: '" + DateStringFixer(dStr));

          dStr = d.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
          dStrAligned = (dStr+"   ").Substring(0,10);
          Console.WriteLine(dStrAligned + "\tby Parsing: '" + DateParser(dStr) + 
              "'\tby replace: '" + DateStringFixer(dStr) + "\n");

      }      
          Console.WriteLine("Malformed input:");

          var dStr2 = "24/7/365 service";
          Console.WriteLine(dStr2 + "\tby Parsing: '" + DateParser(dStr2) +
              "'\tby replace: '" + DateStringFixer(dStr2));
    }

    public static void Main() { Test(); }
}
```

Output:

```
01/01/2017    by Parsing: '01-01-2017'    by replace: '01-01-2017
01/1/2017     by Parsing: '01-01-2017'    by replace: '01-1-2017
1/01/2017     by Parsing: '01-01-2017'    by replace: '1-01-2017
1/1/2017      by Parsing: '01-01-2017'    by replace: '1-1-2017

01/12/2017    by Parsing: '01-12-2017'    by replace: '01-12-2017
01/12/2017    by Parsing: '01-12-2017'    by replace: '01-12-2017
1/12/2017     by Parsing: '01-12-2017'    by replace: '1-12-2017
1/12/2017     by Parsing: '01-12-2017'    by replace: '1-12-2017

== removed lots of similar output ==

12/30/2017    by Parsing: '12-30-2017'    by replace: '12-30-2017
12/30/2017    by Parsing: '12-30-2017'    by replace: '12-30-2017
12/30/2017    by Parsing: '12-30-2017'    by replace: '12-30-2017
12/30/2017    by Parsing: '12-30-2017'    by replace: '12-30-2017

Malformed input:
24/7/365 service    by Parsing: ''    by replace: '24-7-365 service
```

Comment: @Steve thanks for the catch - would have accepted months till 59 that way

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The date that I am getting is not a fixed one. It will be picked by the user via a Calendar in WebForm. So, I can't use Solution 1 and 2.

Comment: @DreamCode - If you copy this 1:1 you can't. You can replace `"04/21/2017"` with whatever string your date comes is - f.e. `Request.QueryString["FromDate"]`. Both solutions will work if `Request.QueryString["FromDate"]` is a string. Just make sure you do NOT use "mm/dd/yyyy" as pattern - this will "parse ok" even for inputs like "47/31/2017" because `"mm"` is the shorthand for `Minutes` in parsing - not `Months`. If you data comes from a date picker it will not happen b/c it validates internally as well. Any reviewer of your code might notice your mistake though.

Comment: @DreamCode I reworked my sample. 2 Funtions that will convert your string to your format + Testcode. Simply use `var newdate = DateParser(Request.QueryString["FromDate"]);`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to convert the date you are receiving from query string into a `DateTime` object

```
string fromDateQS = Request.QueryString["FromDate"];
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fromDateQS, "mm/dd/yyyy", null);
```

After this, you can achieve date of your desired format from the `dt` object.

```
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy");
```

or

```
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Comment: I am writing the following in destination: 

`fromDateQSString = Request.QueryString["FromDate"];`
`DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fromDateQSString, "mm/dd/yyyy", null);`
`string formattedDate = dt.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy");`

And I am sending the date from the Source Page as following: 

` DateTime shortDateQS = Convert.ToDateTime(GridViewSavingsTracker.Rows[rowID].Cells[6].Text);`
`string shortDateString = shortDateQS.ToShortDateString();`

Comment: Your solution is faulty. Given a `fromDateQS` of `"45/14/2017"` it will produce "45-14-2017" - you are parsing/printing `"minutes-days-years"`

Answer (score 1):

`TryParse` should work fine here, it takes a string as a parameter and if it can parse it, it will output it to your `DateTime` object that you pass as the second parameter.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string fromDateQS = Request.QueryString["FromDate"];
DateTime dt = new DateTime();

if (DateTime.TryParse(fromDateQS, out dt))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
}
```

I prefer `TryParse` over `ParseExact` due to an exception can be thrown with `ParseExact` if it is unable to parse the string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am working on ASP.NET and not on Console Application. So, `Console.WriteLine()` won't work.

Comment: Well, the `Console` is just an example of how to use it after you have it in your `DateTime` format.  You just need the `dt.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy")` for your new string.

Comment: Yeah. I know. I thought you didn't know that the question was regarding ASP.NET.

Comment: @DreamCode don't take answers literally. We won't create an ASP.net solution rebuilding your exact scenario if it is not needed to answer a question. For this, simple console is enough.

Comment: @Baddack  Your solution is faulty, you are printing `Minutes-Days-Years` not `Month-Days-Years`